# I want to assign different slug value to subcategory in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Have Category Like

ABC (ParentCategory)
 -PQR (subcategory)
 -XYZ
 -MNP

as per wordPress default functionality all category URL is

"/category/ABC/PQR/post_name", 
"/category/ABC/XYZ/post_name", 
"/category/ABC/MNP/post_name",

But for mycase, I want to just change slug value of the particular subcategory for e.g

Category Name PQR Slug John

so, Whenever we hit on PQR Tab url will be "/category/ABC/John/post_name"

Have tried updating slug value with wordPress admin,  same subcategory post are not visible on production.

Answer (score 0):

Update the slug for the categories and then try updating Permalink Settings in settings > permalinks

and set it again to previous.

Comment: but permalink is change for all subcategory, here I need one particular subcategory slug needs to be change.

Comment: "and set it again to previous." The changes you are making does effect after resetting permalinks.